# Any sample of V4 universal printer driver

Tags: v4-printer-driver

Does anybody know a sample of V4 Universal Printer Driver?

Actually, I was looking for a sample in last two days but I did not found any instance. All Universal Printer Drivers from many vendors are based on V3 print driver model.
It seems that close coupling among data files and V4 print driver model makes it difficult (even practically impossible) to develop UPDs.

Comment: [Link](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1967896-hp-universal-print-driver-type-4) and [Link](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Printers-Archive-Read-Only/UPD-v4-driver-for-Server-2012-R2/m-p/5948049/highlight/true#M102640).It seems that others also are dealing with the same question. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I found a sample from Xerox. See [here](https://atyourservice.blogs.xerox.com/2018/07/10/new-xerox-global-print-driver-v4-and-v3/) and [here](https://www.support.xerox.com/support/global-printer-driver/downloads/enus.html?operatingSystem=win10x64&fileLanguage=en_GB).
Xerox has released this driver package near a month ago (29.OCT.2018).

From my personal point of view it is not still a Global/Universal print/printer driver.

There are more than 250, .gpd files and more than 230 .dpb (driver property bag) files inside the package to cover all product range, means vendors have to create different .gpd (and may be .dpb) file for every single printer or even printer model.

It seems that there is a very long way to make this issue possible using this model.

Comment: It is interesting that the issue still open from 2013. See the following link: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/08e5846e-876f-4239-b510-67920abf4a72/why-cant-win7-clients-print-to-shared-type4-driver-printers?forum=winserver8gen

Comment: The same issue also discussed in this link: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1967896-hp-universal-print-driver-type-4